# ZAP ScriptWriter synch error

Tags: docker, hsqldb, owasp, zap

I'm running ZAP attack proxy from docker image (owasp/zap2docker) https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/zap2docker-stable/

Periodically I run into this error (once it occurs for the first time, everything goes the wrong way)

> 30130034 [HSQLDB Timer @28b04679] WARN hsqldb.db..ENGINE  -
>   ScriptWriter synch error:  java.io.SyncFailedException: sync failed
>     at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(Native Method)   at
>   org.hsqldb.lib.FileUtil$FileSync.sync(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptWriterBase.forceSync(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptWriterBase.sync(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptWriterBase.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlTimer$TaskRunner.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Physically - I've checked - there is plenty of space in both container and environment (lot of free inodes, lot of physical space). I'm running aws m3.large instance (2 cores, 7.5GB RAM, 1x32GB SSD disk). Any clue what might be causing it, or how to circumvent that error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is raised when the changes written to the .log file is synced to disk and means the sync was unsuccessful. This failure clearly shows the disk system is unreliable.

Comment: Hmh - I'm able to reproduce it on lot of different machines (I'm using AWS) - so I wonder if this isn't some threading issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that one before :(
As you're probably aware its an HSQLDB error rather than a ZAP one.
Do you get it when running the weekly docker image?

Comment: So it is possible to switch to some other db engine ? I'll try the weekly image & let you know.

Comment: Errr, ish ;) We do support other db engines (eg MySQL) but its _very_ experimental: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-develop/Ivh3MnGyo6k/2bMHjgTmw6gJ

We do plan to support other db engines fully fairly soon...

Comment: The weekly image is just wrong :) It runs one thread per host / ignores /UI/ascan/action/setOptionThreadPerHost/ - at the size of site I'm scanning it would take forever.

Comment: Oh :( Could you raise a bug for that? https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues Thanks.